# How do I remove the grey background around my picture?

Tags: html, css

How do I remove the grey background around my picture?
Here's how the page looks right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VYM6.jpg

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-style: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/vga");
  padding: 10%;
  margin: 0%;
  border: 0%;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the background-color:grey; from the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the body has margin, so:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to remove the color of background?

```
background-color: grey;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this snippet of code:

`body {
            background-color: grey;
        }`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Set the parent element 'height, width' same as that of the image, and set overflow: hidden; to that parent element, which will cut out the grey area.

Answer (score 0):

Your background-image needs to fill perfectly the header to hide the grey background.
Try with :

```
.header {
background-size:100% auto;
}
```

or

```
.header {
background-size: cover; /* or contain */
}
```

Hope this helps